# insertBefore and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

First apologies, the pages I working on a behind passwords, I hope this is enough but if you'd like more code, just ask!

I've got a webpage that list events, each event is a complex set of elements all wrapped in an relative positioned div, an eventRow.

When adding a new event, I find where it should be placed and use:

```
document.getElementById('eventRows').insertBefore(div, document.getElementById('eventRow' + id));
```

div is the new event row, id is the id of the event I want to insert before!

This works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE8, but in IE7 it goes wrong - the new event row seems to be placed correctly, but the rows that surround it aren't correctly moved out of the way, leaving a mess of overlapping text.

After a while I found this can be fixed, after the insert, using the code:

```
$('eventRows').innerHTML = $('eventRows').innerHTML;
```

So I've almost solved it, but I'm not very happy, any thoughts on the following questions:

Should I just do this as it seems to work?

Should I only do it if the browser is IE7?

Should I find a better fix?

Many thanks

Ben.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `)` in your first jQuery example above. Is that just the case here, or in your code as well?

Comment: Quite right - I'd trimmed down the code for clarity - I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try forcing a redraw. There are a few ways that I can think of:

- The one you describe
- `node.className = node.className` is reported to work although I've never tried it.
- Append a text node
- Add a class and then remove it.
- Make other style changes and then remove them (padding, border, margin)

Append a text node:

```
function redraw(node) {
  var doc = node.ownerDocument;
  var text = doc.createTextNode(' ');
  node.appendChild(text);
  setTimeout(function() {
    node.removeChild(text);
  },0);
}
```

Add/Remove a class

```
function redraw(node) {
  node.className += ' redraw';
  setTimeout(function() {
    node.className = node.className.replace(/\sredraw$/, '');
  }, 0);
}
```

*This code is untested since I don't have IE7*

These methods also exist in the various libraries out there. For Ext it's `Element.repaint()`. There is a force_redraw plugin for jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/content/forceredraw-102. I'm sure there are others, I just don't know about them.

Comment: I've tested all your suggestions, all of which work (including className=className) with one exception - I have an absolute positioned checkbox (not the only AP div) which does not appear unless I do innerHTML=innerHTML - so should I just stick with this? should I filter out working browsers?

Comment: @Ben I've read that the AP divs can be a problem. I recall seeing a solution out there. Let me take a look around.

Comment: @Ben Have you looked at the source for [force_redraw?](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.forceredraw-1.0.2.js_.txt) The claim is that the `brutal` (add and then remove padding) method will handle absolutely positioned nodes. If you've tried that (and maybe a version with margin) then I think you should stick to the `innerHTML` method, but I would only filter out the working browsers if you have performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing I've plumped for the following:

```
function redrawElement(e) {
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) <= 7) {
        e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML
    }
}
```

Many of the other ideas nearly worked, but not quite, the padding idea worked once, but caused a nasty jump with the timeout, this does't seem to clause any issues with performance - so why not! :-)

Thanks for your help!!